# How to set width of XIB-View to displaywidth

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, uistackview

I have my own xib-file looking like this:

[image]

Now I programmatically add multiple instances of this XIB-`View` to my original View which is a `UIStackView` with full width inside of a `UIScrollView` which takes the whole screen size.

I want to achieve, that every instance of my xib-view has the whole displayWidth. This is what I tried:

```
myView.frame.size = CGSize(myView.frame.size.height, view.frame.size.width())
```

But I can't change the view's width with this code. How do I achieve to change the width?

**Edit:** This is how I add the views (it is in java because I am using multi-os-engine but It is almost exactly like in objective-c)

```
@Override
@Selector("viewDidLoad")
public void viewDidLoad() {
    UIView checkBox = instantiateFromNib("CheckBoxView");
    for (UIView v : checkBox.subviews()) {
        if (v instanceof DLRadioButton) {
            ((DLRadioButton) v).setTitleForState(option.getName(), UIControlState.Normal);
        }
    }
    configView.addArrangedSubview(checkBox);
}

private UIView instantiateFromNib(String name) {
        return (UIView) UINib.nibWithNibNameBundle(name, null).instantiateWithOwnerOptions(null, null).firstObject();
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code where you add your views to the stackview?

Comment: @CatalinaT. Please see my edit

Comment: which one is the `stackView`? also could you post `addArrangedSubview`?

Comment: @CatalinaT. `configView` is the stackView. What do you mean? This is not a method from me.